# How do I get BootstrapTable to redraw with updated data?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, redraw, react-bootstrap-table

I have a Table from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) that displays a list of devices with several columns. I want to change this so you can reorder by the columns so I switched to BootstrapTable from [react-bootstrap-table-next](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/). But my problem is that changing the state of the Component doesn't cause the table to update - this only happens if I click on a column to reorder the table.

The code is written to create the `devices_table` and save it to state then call an API to get the device version and add that to the state, causing the component to redraw. But when `render()` is called again the additional data isn't added to the table.

I've created a working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-next-new-data-problem-5w0op

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next'

class DeviceTable extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            devices_table: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.devices !== this.props.devices) {
            let devices_table = this.props.devices.map(this.myFunction);
            this.setState({
                devices_table: devices_table
            })
        }
    }

    myFunction = (value, index, array) => {
        let device = {};

        device.device = value;
        device.index = index + 1;
        device.version = '';

        apiGetDeviceVersion(value.identifier)
            .then((res, deviceId = value.identifier) => {
                let devices_table = this.state.devices_table;
                let objIndex = devices_table.findIndex(d => d.device.identifier === deviceId)
                devices_table[objIndex].version = res.valueReported;
                this.setState({
                    devices_table: devices_table
                })
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            })

        return device;
    }

    render() {
        const devices = this.state.devices_table;
        if (isEmpty(devices)) {
            return (<div></div>)
        }
        let columns = [
            {
                text: "#",
                dataField: "index",
                sort: true
            },
            {
                text: "ID",
                dataField: "device.identifier",
                sort: true
            },
            {
                text: "Name",
                dataField: "device.name",
                sort: true
            },
            {
                text: "Status",
                dataField: "device.status",
                sort: true
            },
            {
                text: "Version",
                dataField: "version",
                sort: true
            }
        ];

        return (
            <div>
                <BootstrapTable keyField={"device.identifier"} data={devices} columns={columns}></BootstrapTable>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DeviceTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
   if (prevProps.devices !== this.props.devices) {
            *let devices_table* = this.props.devices.map(this.myFunction);
            this.setState({
                devices_table: devices_table
            })
        }
}
```

It may happen due to response is working as asynchronous function(because of API). Thus, you have to wait for the response to make it available, otherwise "devices_table" remains empty or undefined and leads to no data visualization.

Comment: Yes, that's why the result of the API call gets added to the state when it returns so `devices_table` updates.